# More than 12 columns DataTable/Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I have a question.
I'm doing a DataTable and I want to style it with Bootstrap grid system for make it responsive.
So, my Table has more than 12 cols and when I try to use the grid system, some info does backspace or dates goes truncated:

```
14-06-
2017
```

My table is something like this:

```html
<table>
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>ID</th>
       <th>Descripción</th>
       <th>Responsable</th>
       <th>Estado</th>
       <th style="display:none">Pos.</th>
       <th >Inicio</th>
       <th>Finalización</th>
       <th style="display:none">F. estim.</th>
       <th>Tiempo</th>
       <th >Puesto de Trabajo</th>
       <th>Responsable proceso</th>
       <th>Nº Oportunidad</th>
       <th>Archivo</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>...</td>
       <td>...</td>
       <td>...</td>
       <td>...</td>
       <td hidden>...</td>
       <td>...</td>
       <td>...</td>
       <td hidden>...</td>
       <td>...</td>
       <td>...</td>
       <td>...</td>
       <td>...</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
```

First of all, it doesn't work well if I put `class="col-*-*"` (where -*-* are device and size) on `<th>` doesn't work, and if I put in `<td>` doesn't fit.
Also, headers lose alignment because of the sort arrows. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.
[image]

Comment: do you want bootstrap with more than 12 columns?

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: How can I do a 13 column table responsive and effective if bootstrap has 12 column with DataTable?

Comment: You can't use `.col-*-*` as a class appended to a table column.  You would have to create a whole grid structure within each cell (ie. `<td><div class="row"><div class="col-md-2">A</div>...`) and at that point you're using a table for layout structure.

Comment: I have a div class= "row " and inside of it I have the table with the structure mentioned before. Thank you for answering

Comment: Have you considered wrapping your table in a `.table-responsive` element? This will create an X-axis scrollbar for table overflow.  Otherwise you would likely need to rely on responsive `.hidden-*` classes to hide unnecessary columns at specific breakpoints.

Comment: I will try tomorrow this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need css's **white-space** property:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

t.e. 6th td on each row should be:

```
<td style="white-space: nowrap;">...</td>
```

If you are using bootstrap, then it could be better to use class **text-nowrap**:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/#text-wrapping-and-overflow

t.e. 6t td on each row should be:

```
<td class="text-nowrap">...</td>
```

But after you are using bootstarp with DataTable i recommend to use DataTable's property **columnDefs**:

https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs

t.e.:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [ {
      "targets": 6,
      "className": "text-nowrap"
    } ]
} );
```